Stuck in a loop of fix-broken install error after upgrading from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04 due to libogrenextmain2.3.3 not installed
I'm stuck in a loop of fix-broken install error after upgrading from Ubuntu 22.04 to Ubuntu 24.04 due libogrenextmain2.3.3 not installed.
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libogre-next-dev : Depends: libogrenextmain2.3.3 (= 2.3.3+dfsg-0ubuntu2) but it is not installed
 libogrenexthlmspbs2.3.3 : Depends: libogrenextmain2.3.3 (>= 2.3.3+dfsg) but it is not installed
 libogrenexthlmsunlit2.3.3 : Depends: libogrenextmain2.3.3 (>= 2.3.3+dfsg) but it is not installed
 libogrenextmeshlodgenerator2.3.3 : Depends: libogrenextmain2.3.3 (>= 2.3.3+dfsg) but it is not installed
 libogrenextoverlay2.3.3 : Depends: libogrenextmain2.3.3 (>= 2.3.3+dfsg) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Results of sudo apt --fix-broken install :
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libogrenextmain2.3.3
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libogrenextmain2.3.3
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 297 not upgraded.
34 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2,384 kB of archives.
After this operation, 7,685 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
...
...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libogrenextmain2.3.3_2.3.3+dfsg-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I tried all the methods provided in this link to fix the above Sub-process Error, but ended up with suggestion to apt --fix-broken install which drives me into an error loop.
Additionally I tried to understand about the libogrenextmain2.3.3 package that's causing  the issue and found this.
It looks like it is a proposal to remove the above package from Ubuntu. I'm not sure if it's already removed, and what is the alternative chosen for backward compatibility with some of the libraries listed in the error message of the first command.

Remove the complete ogre-next with all its dependencies: sudo apt remove ogre-next. Make sure that no other packages are removed besides those from the ogre-next package.
ogre is necessary for blender so keep track if and which packages of blender would get uninstalled as well.
Reinstall blender, if necessary, ogre-next separately.
This should fix your issue.
